# How to add each digit in a string of numbers with no spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently trying to take a sequence of numbers in a string input, and then convert those numbers into a total to print. In concept this should be easy, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. I've searched Stack but could not find a solution that fits my current problem.

This is my current progress:

```
def main():
numbers= input("Enter a sequence of numbers with no spaces:")
numbers= list(numbers)
total= ""
for i in numbers:
    total= total + i

print(total)
```

main()

My logic is to break the sequence of numbers into a list, then add the numbers in a loop, to then produce the total. Unfortunately this only returns the original string, so I decided to put:

for i in numbers:

```
i= eval(i)
total= total + i
```

and

for i in numbers:

```
i= int(i)
total= total + i
```

This returns an error stating that i needs to be a string, but this will only lead to another concatenation.

Does anyone know how to produce what I'm looking for?  ie "1234" = 10.

Comment: Try making `total= 0` as your starting point. For an int the `+` operation is addition. For a string the `+` operation is concatenation, which means to join the two strings into a new string. So you'd just be rejoining the string you just split. You'd also need to convert `i` to int to add to existing total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string itself is an iterable, so you can iterate over it and convert each character to an int and then use sum to add them.

```
>>> numbers= input("Enter a sequence of numbers with no spaces:")
Enter a sequence of numbers with no spaces:1234567
>>> sum([int(i) for i in numbers])
28
```

or lose the outer `[]` to make it a generator expression. It will work either way, however for a small input like this arguably the generator overhead might exceed its benefits in terms of memory usage.

Comment: Thanks that works beautifully, I was definitely over complicating things. Thanks again and once it lets me I'll acknowledge this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need to turn the string into a list, since it’s already an iterable. Instead, just do something like this:

```
numbers = input(‘Enter numbers: ‘)
total = 0

for char in numbers:
    total += int(char)

print(total)
```

This goes through each character in the string, turns it into an integer, and adds it to the total.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more answer here. If your string that you are accepting is comma seperated, then here is a one liner if it is python 2.7

```
 sequence = map(int, input().split(','))
```

else for python3,

```
sequence = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
```

I hope it adds something to already given answers.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've used the split function on other examples, but since this has no separators it complicated things, thank you anyways for your input!

Comment: But the way you are using, you wont be able to distinguish between one digit numbers and more than one digit numbers. All will be same for your code.